# How do I prepare a new device in Configurator without updating the device iOS?

Tags: apple-configurator

I need to install an in-house application on a few company ipods. In order to get  them into supervised mode I need to use the Perpare function of Apple Configurator. However, I cannot unselect the 'Update iOS' option, and the app to be installed is iOS7 only.

Answer (score 2):

Place the required version iOS ipsw file here:

~/Library/Containers/com.apple.configurator/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.configurator/Firmware/

Use the Edit Custom iOS Versions command
In Apple Configurator, hold down the Option key while choosing Devices > Edit Custom iOS Versions. You can then add or remove custom versions of iOS software, such as developer previews.

source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT200241?viewlocale=en_US